# App to listen to the phone's volume buttons' events

Tags: javascript, android, progressive-web-apps

I need to create an app to listen to the phone's volume buttons' events.
As far as I could find and test, a simple page with javascript doesn't trigger those events, using something like this:
`window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler)`
Does making it a PWA change anything?
The requirement is only for Android.
Triggering when the app is closed or when the phone is locked is a big plus.

The easiest alternative I think can do the job is React Native. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're multiple platforms to archive this and the easiest way I think fit you is:

**1- Ionic**:

It's based on `cordova` and it's the closet platform to `PWA` that you already using and you can handle volume buttons using this library from [here](https://github.com/manueldeveloper/cordova-plugin-volume-buttons).

`cordova-plugin-volume-buttons`.

```
window.addEventListener("volumebuttonslistener", onVolumeButtonsListener, false);
    
    function onVolumeButtonsListener(info){
        console.log("Button pressed: " + info.signal);
    }
```

**2- React Native**

This will give you the best performance  and you can handle volume buttons using this library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-volume-control).

`react-native-volume-control`

```
import VolumeControl, {
  VolumeControlEvents
} from "react-native-volume-control";

VolumeControlEvents.addListener(
      "VolumeChanged",
      this.volumeEvent
    );
```

---

You can check if the app closed or gone to background using `AppState` like this example:

```
import {AppState} from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    // remove subscription
    return AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
}, []);

const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
   // closed
   if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
   console.log('the app is closed');
  }   else if (nextAppState === 'background') {
     console.log('the app on background');
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to test with react native. Do you know anything about the app being closed or the phone locked?

Comment: You're welcome :D , Can you mark it as a correct answer, and about the app close on react native you can use AppState I've update my answer please take a look and tell me if there's anything you want :D

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think that being closed or the phone locked triggers on volume change that way, right?

Comment: I did a little search To achieve this you need to go for native, you can make a native class using `Native Modules` on android/ios with react native.